# How do I prevent PHP file from popping up after submitting contact form?

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

Right now, whenever I click the submit button on the contact form on my website, it brings me to the page www.mysite.com/php/function/email.php, rather than running the email.php in the background like I want it to.

The website is supposed to allow you to submit the contact form, then the button will fade away and fade in a "Your message has been sent!", then fade back the button.

HTML:

```
<form name="contact form" id='contact_form' method="post" action="php/function/email.php">
<div class="row half">
    <div class="6u">
        <input name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" class="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="6u">
        <input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" class="text" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row half">
    <div class="12u">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row half">
    <div class="12u">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message" class="button button-icon icon icon-envelope" />
    </div>
</div>
<p id="success" style="display:none">Your message has been sent! I'll get back to you soon!</p>
        <p id="error" style="display:none">Please fill in all the fields and try again!</p>
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#send_message').click(function(e){

        //Stop form submission & check the validation
        e.preventDefault();

        // Variable declaration
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var subject = $('#subject').val();
        var message = $('#message').val();

       // Disable submit button just after the form processed 1st time successfully.
        $('#send_message').attr({'disabled' : 'true', 'value' : 'Sending...' });

        /* Post Ajax function of jQuery to get all the data from the submission of the form as soon as the form sends the values to email.php*/
        $.post("email.php", $("#contact_form").serialize(),function(result){
            //Check the result set from email.php file.
            if(result == 'sent'){
                //If the email is sent successfully, remove the submit button
                 $('#submit').remove();
                //Display the success message
                $('#success').fadeIn(500);
            }else{
                //Display the error message
                $('#error').fadeIn(500);
                // Enable the submit button again
                $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled').attr('value', 'Send The Message');
            }
        });
    }
});    
};
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: Example'; 
$to = 'example@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Example Contact Form';

$body = "
From: $name
Email: $email
---------------
Message: \n
$message";
if ($_POST['submit']) {              
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo 'sent';
} else { 
    echo 'failed';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I never have fully trusted in the preventDefault, put a "return false" in the end of your function to make trully sure it will not trigger the submit...

Comment: @Roger You can trust it, but it's only effective for events that have a default action (most don't). Using `return false;` in a jQuery event is just shorthand for calling both `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.click()` event of a `<input type="submit">` isn't actually what causes the redirection. It instead becomes a [`.submit()` event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) at the `<form>`.

You can either [`e.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) so it doesn't reach the `<form>`.

```
//Stop form submission & check the validation
e.stopPropagation();
```

Or `preventDefault()` of the `<form>`'s `.submit()`.

```
$('#contact_form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Note: You should also consider moving your code into a `.submit()` handler as most browsers support other ways of submitting a `<form>` than actually clicking the `<input type="submit">`.

Comment: Add to that, submitting a form by hitting <Enter> won't click the submit button anyway.  Handling the form's submit event makes sure you're catching all (user-initiated) attempts to submit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just tried moving my code into a .submit() handler while using e.preventDefault(), but I still have the same problem. I also tried return:false; and e.stopPropagation, but neither stop me from being directed to the PHP page.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're looking for click events on `#send_message` but your submit button has an id of `submit`. So that click event never happens.